# Super slow SQL query when `WHERE` and `OR` are used together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following `SQL` query running on `MYSQL` and it is super slow -

```
SELECT * FROM xyz USE INDEX (xyz_idx) WHERE col_1 = 'ZETA' OR col_2 = 'ZETA'
```

I have set the indexing as follows -

```
CREATE INDEX xyz_idx ON xyz (col_1(20), col_2(20))
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong with the query or index?

FYI... after removing `OR`, the following SQL works superfast but I do need to have `OR` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM xyz USE INDEX (xyz_idx) WHERE col_1 = 'ZETA'
```

Comment: You might need to create individual indexes on `col1` and `col2` instead of a combined index.

Comment: @Rocker, your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks! Can you please reply as the answer?

Comment: `OR` is slow.  "Prefix" indexing (eg, `col_1(20)`) is virtually useless.  Two, separate, non-prefixed, indexes, plus a `UNION` is the likely speedup.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. Is this a good way to make two non-prefixed indexs? ```CREATE INDEX xyz_idx ON xyz col_1;
CREATE INDEX xyz_idx ON xyz col_2;```

Comment: @Saurabh - What is the datatype of `col_1`?

Comment: It's a ```character``` type.